# Optimize Swift Code (switch case)

Tags: switch-statement, swift

im new to Swift an looking for someone to help me optimize my code.. im almost 100% sure that it can be written much smarter than what i did here. And this is just some of the code.. the Switch will be 4 times longer than this.. Help me do this in some easy way :)

```
func calc(distance:Int, male:Bool, longhitter:Bool){
    switch (distance,male,longhitter){
    case (237..600,true,true):
        LblResultat.text = Clubs[1]
    case (215..237,true,true):
        LblResultat.text = Clubs[2]
    case (190..215,true,true):
        LblResultat.text = Clubs[3]
    case (170..190,true,true):
        LblResultat.text = Clubs[4]
    case (155..170,true,true):
        LblResultat.text = Clubs[5]
    case (145..155,true,true):
        LblResultat.text = Clubs[6]
    case (135..145,true,true):
        LblResultat.text = Clubs[7]
    case (130..135,true,true):
        LblResultat.text = Clubs[8]
    case (120..130,true,true):
        LblResultat.text = Clubs[9]
    case (110..120,true,true):
        LblResultat.text = Clubs[10]
    case (100..110,true,true):
        LblResultat.text = Clubs[11]
    case (90..100,true,true):
        LblResultat.text = Clubs[12]
    case (80..90,true,true):
        LblResultat.text = Clubs[12]
    default:
        LblResultat.text = "None found"
    }
}
```

Thanks heaps :)

Comment: You could come up with an equation that would get the right index from the distance, but that won't be good for clarity

Comment: Why don't you only switch on `distance`, instead of that tuple? Would certainly make it a bunch more readable.

Comment: @JackWu From his statement it will be four times as long, I guess the other three booleans are not yet there.

Comment: Since in the example code male,long hitter must be true test for this in an if() and then switch simply on distance. Also you only net to set a vat to the index and have one `Cubs[index]` statement. Elimination duplications is good, it is the "DRY" principle or writing code.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus You are correct. This is with both true, next step would be one false, one true, then true:false and false:false.

Comment: Just have a table with the thresholds [80,90,100,...,237,600] and use binary search to find the right index. (Or with such a small number of cases, simple linear scan.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a static 3-dimensional lookup table. For the distance, you will either need a case statement to convert it into an index, or a combination of arithmetic and if-then-else (for the first two cases, for sure), or you can set boundary points in a sorted list and use binary search. In fact, you could even generate the table (separately) as 600x2x2, and write a utility that creates the initialization code. That is, outputs the 600x2x2 table, which you could use in a static initializer.

Comment: I have no idea how to do what you just wrote.. Some part of it I dont even understand xD .. I will do some more research regarding your answer

Comment: Jukka Suomela's comment is on the same lines as this answer. You are going to have an array of (pardon my not knowing Swift, but this syntax should be about right) `int index[14][2][2];` (14 is my guess on number of first indexes.) The entries for `index[*][1][1]`, where true is 1, are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,…,12, 12. You use a binary search to figure out what the correct first index is. You assign some variable to `Clubs[index[index_I_got_by_binary_search_on_breakpoints_of_distance][male][longhitter]]`. The entire table can be initialized at compile time. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Your data smells an exponential curve, something that is inversely proportional to the square of the distance.

I'm posting something **just for fun**, in case a mathematical approach might help you in your case -- and I can't guess if it will, based on the facts you provided.

I tried some [curve fitting](http://www.had2know.com/academics/regression-calculator-statistics-best-fit.html) on your data and it seemed like your x,y data strongly resembled this:

```
y = round(100000 ^ -2)
```

Now, the resulting y's might vary a little bit here and there:

```
 85     14
 95     12
105     10
115      8
125      7
132      6
140      6
150      5
165      4
180      4
200      3
220      3
400      1
599      1
```

But we can make sure they won't overflow with one line of code.

This approach gives you a very simple way of coding your solution:

```
func calc(distance:Int, male:Bool, longhitter:Bool) {
    var index: Int?

    switch (male,longhitter){
        case (true, true):
            index = calcIndex(distance, 100_000, -2)
        case (true, false):
            index = calcIndex(distance, 90_000, -2)
        // ...
    default:
        break
    }

    if index {
        LblResultat.text = Clubs[index!]
    }
}

func calcIndex(distance: Int, multiplier: Double, power: Double) -> Int {
    let index = Int(multiplier * pow(Double(distance), power) + 0.5);
    return max(1, min(index, 12))
}
```

As you can see, you can "fine-tune" the curve for males, females, long hitters or not, etc.

Since your data seems to come from Physics, then why not use Mathematics to build the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
func calc2(distance:Int, male:Bool, longhitter:Bool) -> String {
    switch (male, longhitter) {
        case (true, true):
            let posts = [600, 237, 215, 190, 170, 155, 145, 135, 130, 120, 110, 100, 80]
            for i in 0..posts.count - 1 {
                if distance < posts[i] && distance > posts[i + 1] {
                    return clubs[i]
                }
            }
            return "not found"
        case (true, false):
            // when you do have data, do the same thing here
            return "no data"
        case (false, true):
            // when you do have data, do the same thing here
            return "no data"
        case (false, false):
            // when you do have data, do the same thing here
            return "no data"
        default:
            return "wtf?"
    }
}
```

I changed "Clubs" to "clubs" as I guess it's an array, not a type, and I'm returning a String, rather than building the UI dependency into the logic.

Having so many magic numbers hard coded is generally a bad idea, and an approach like this allows you to load the data array from file or otherwise update it later.